# Simplify an Java boolean compare

Tags: java, boolean, equals

I have found an method equals that compares two moves and I want to simplify it.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Move other = (Move) obj;
    return !(this.initialBalls != other.initialBalls &&
            (this.initialBalls == null || !this.initialBalls.equals(other.initialBalls)))
            && this.direction == other.direction && this.color == other.color;
}
```

Someone have an idea ?

Comment: Maybe the guys of CodeReview can help you: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That return statement is needlessly complex. Head over to CR and I'll gladly provide something more simple.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about codereview and as such belongs on that site.

Comment: Why simplify it? Just make it more readable, it seems ok...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [EqualsBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) from Apache Commons.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) { return false; }
    if (obj == this) { return true; }
    if (obj.getClass() != getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    Move rhs = (Move) obj;
    return new EqualsBuilder()
        .appendSuper(super.equals(obj))
        .append(initialBalls, rhs.initialBalls)
        .append(direction, rhs.direction)
        .append(color, rhs.color)
        .isEquals();
    }
```

Comment: Why the extra dependency just for that?

Comment: Why not? Was there a constraint that I missed in the OP that no 3rd party libraries were allowed? Do you know the correct way to implement `equals()` when the fields you're comparing are floating point values? Do you trust all the developers you work with do too? It also saves a lot of `null` checks if your fields aren't primitives.

Comment: Red herring much? You still fail to justify using a full library for something you can easily fix on your own just by adding a few spaces / new lines in the right place or by moving a few characters around. And I'm not speaking in general, but about OP's task, which is absolutely trivial.

Comment: @user16547 So you can fix floating point comparisons by moving a few characters around and adding spaces and new lines? Do you know the data type of the `direction` and `color` fields being compared in the OP? Why NOT use a library that handles everything appropriately instead of rolling your own solution? Based on what you've said here, the solution you come up with is likely to fail in ways you don't expect.

Comment: @user16547 It's very telling that you haven't been able to provide an answer to this question.

Comment: @MikeB Did I ever said that about floats? No. The OP asked about simplifying that method. Instead of answering the question precisely and maybe mentioning the pitfalls when those fields are floats, you're suggesting a potentially useless dependency, because "why not?" and "what if?".

Comment: @user16547 Once you've worked on a non-trivial application you'll understand. I could tell the OP how to write this particular `equals` method, then when he runs in to a case where that approach falls down he'll be right back here on SO. Or I can show him how to write an `equals` method that he can use for every custom object he implements. Sometimes you need to look at bigger picture. The ability to do so will come with experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator if you want to write it in one line:

```
return (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) ? false : [TODO: check if they are equal];
```